# Can I fix my fried notebook?

Tags: power-electronics, repair, laptop

so I'm feeling sad today, as I fried my notebook. I took apart a SATA to USB device and soldered a connector to the 12v line, so I could use full sized HDDs with my USB adapter.

I have already tested it before on a RPi, and worked, but when I tried on my notebook, the moment I plugged in the 12v source (the 5v was already plugged in via USB), it shut down, and with no signs of life.. not even the charging LED turns on now..

What could have possibly happened? I hoped there would be a safety fuse or something in cases such as there.. Is there any hope for my poor notebook? It is an Asus X555UB, and I have some hobbyist experience in electronics, can I try to fix it?

### EDIT

There's light at the end of the tunnel after all, and after opening it up and removing the internal battery, the notebook seems to turn back on! My conclusion is that the notebook's PMS must have some sort of soft kill switch, for such overload cases, and resetting it (removing  all the batteries) seems to make it try again. Well, it's been an adventure of the heart, and one I don't want to get through again

Thank you for everyone that helped, and sorry for posting in the wrong manner.

Regards

Comment: [Comments are not for answering questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). However for those people who want to help the OP, this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131967/discussion-on-question-by-leandragem-can-i-fix-my-fried-notebook), which is the correct place for giving that off-topic help.